# AspectJ : Compile time Weaving forced to throw exception

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

Note : Using `compile time weaving.`

I have an AOP interceptor something like

```
@Around("enableMetricsPointCut(enableMetrics)")
public Object publishMetrics(final ProceedingJoinPoint jp,
            final EnableMetrics enableMetrics) {
    // Catch all Checked exceptions and convert them to unCheckedExceptions
}
```

Now, I have annotated a method using this AOP annotation something like

```
@EnableMetrics( )
public xyzMethod() { 
   // Code throws a checkedException : checkME
}
```

I am being forced to add '`throws checkME`' to xyzMethod. Why is this? Considering it is compile time weaving I shouldn't be as my AOP interceptor '`EnableMetrics`' doesn't throw any checked exception and I am using 'around'.

Is there a way to achieve what I am doing? I don't want my methods like xyzMethod to declare any throws.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot.

Annotations are just... annotations. They can be used to avoid display of warning (you tell the compiler you know why you do that), to generate ancilliary code, or .... But anyway, the code obtained by removing the annotation **shall** be correct java code.

As in (current version of) java, checked exception **must** be declared at method level, AOP cannot do anything.

The only possibility would be that at core java level, an annotation allows the use of undeclared checked exceptions. But I do not think it ever exists, because the declaration `throws Throwable` has already that effect.

TL/DR: If you do not want to be bothered by checked exception, add a `throws Throwable` to your method if it is acceptable, or use an explicit wrapping method. Neither AOP nor any other annotation based method can save you from that.